# How to export SQL Database directly to blob storage programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I need to programmatically backup/export a SQL Database (either in Azure, or a compatible-one on-prem) to Azure Storage, and restore it to another SQL Database.  I would like to use only NuGet packages for code dependencies, since I cannot guarantee that either the build or production servers will have the Azure SDK installed.  I cannot find any code examples for something that I assume would be a common action.  The closest I found was this:

https://blog.hompus.nl/2013/03/13/backup-your-azure-sql-database-to-blob-storage-using-code/

But, this code exports to a local bacpac file (requiring RoleEnvironment, an SDK-only object).  I would think there should be a way to directly export to Blob Storage, without the intermediary file.  One thought was to create a Stream, and then run:

```
services.ExportBacpac(stream, "dbnameToBackup")
```

And then write the stream to storage; however a Memory Stream wouldn't work--this could be a massive database (100-200 GB).

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: What about exporting it to local file and then upload the file to Blob Storage via Azure Storage Data Movement Library? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement

Comment: So what eventually did you do?

Comment: We wound up using the DacServices class to call ExportBacpac.  Since our clients are mostly on AWS, I can't say how well this performs.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my test, the [sql Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library 0.51.0-prerelease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/0.51.0-prerelease) support directly export the sql database .bacpac file to the azure storage.

We could using `sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,exportRequestParameters)` to export the .**bacpac** file the **azure storage**.

But we couldn't find ImportExport in the lastest version of Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library SDK.  So we could only use sql Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library 0.51.0-prerelease SDK.

More details about how to use sql Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library to export the sql backup to azure blob storage, you could refer to below steps and codes.

Prerequisites:

Registry an App in Azure AD and create service principle for it. More detail steps about how to registry app and get access token please refer to [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

Details codes:

Notice: Replace the clientId,tenantId,secretKey,subscriptionId with your registered azure AD information. Replace the azureSqlDatabase，resourceGroup，azureSqlServer，adminLogin，adminPassword，storageKey，storageAccount with your own sql database and storage.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx";
    var clientId = "xxxxxxxxx";
    var tenantId = "xxxxxxxx";
    var secretKey = "xxxxx";
    var azureSqlDatabase = "data base name";
    var resourceGroup = "Resource Group name";
    var azureSqlServer = "xxxxxxx"; //testsqlserver 
    var adminLogin = "user";
    var adminPassword = "password";
    var storageKey = "storage key";
    var storageAccount = "storage account";
    var baseStorageUri = $"https://{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/brandotest/";//with container name endwith "/"
    var backName = azureSqlDatabase + "-" + $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmm}" + ".bacpac";  //back up sql file name
    var backupUrl = baseStorageUri + backName;
    ImportExportOperationStatusResponse exportStatus = new ImportExportOperationStatusResponse();
    try
    {
        ExportRequestParameters exportRequestParameters = new ExportRequestParameters
        {
            AdministratorLogin = adminLogin,
            AdministratorLoginPassword = adminPassword,
            StorageKey = storageKey,
            StorageKeyType = "StorageAccessKey",
            StorageUri = new Uri(backupUrl)
        };

        SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));
        var export = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,
                        exportRequestParameters); //do export operation

        while (exportStatus.Status != Microsoft.Azure.OperationStatus.Succeeded) // until operation successed
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
            exportStatus = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.GetImportExportOperationStatus(export.OperationStatusLink);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Export DataBase {azureSqlDatabase} to Storage {storageAccount} Succesfully");
    }

    catch (Exception exception)
    {

        //todo

    }

}

private static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
{
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
    var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
        credential);

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }

    var token = result.Result.AccessToken;
    return token;
}
```

Result like this:

1.Send request to tell sql server start exporting to azure blob storage

[image]

2.Continue sending request to monitor the database exported operation status.

[image]

3.Finish exported operation.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, but we cannot use prerelease software.

Comment: We could also use the sql database export [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export#Databases_Export) to tell the sql server database to export to the azure blob. If you accept this way, I could also provide some code example .

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

Pass the stream to the `.ExportBacPac` method but hold a reference to it on a different thread where you regularly empty and reset the stream so that there's no memory overflow. I'm assuming here, that `Dac` does not have any means to access the stream while it is being filled.

The thing you have to take care of yourself though is thread safety - MemoryStreams are not thread safe by default. So you'd have to write your own locking mechanisms around `.Position` and `.CopyTo`. I've not tested this, but if you handle locking correctly I'd assume the `.ExportBacPac` method won't throw any errors while the other thread accesses the stream.

Here's a very simple example as pseudo-code just outlining my idea:

```cs
ThreadSafeStream stream = new ThreadSafeStream();

Task task = new Task(async (exitToken) => {
    MemoryStream partialStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Check if backup completed
    if (...) 
    {
         exitToken.Trigger();
    }

    stream.CopyToThreadSafe(partialStream);
    stream.PositionThreadSafe = 0;

    AzureService.UploadToStorage(partialStream);

    await Task.Delay(500); // Play around with this - it shouldn't take too long to copy the stream
});

services.ExportBacpac(stream, "dbnameToBackup");

await TimerService.RunTaskPeriodicallyAsync(task, 500);
```

Comment: I'm not thrilled with introducing locking.  In previous experience, locking has been a great source of pain.  Also creating a new thread in infrastructure code (which is what I am writing) is problematic since the application code can choose to create hundreds of threads to perform various parallel tasks, causing the upload thread to be starved out; eventually leading to a timeout.  (Again, this has happened before.)

Comment: Maybe you can answer this as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409710/error-restoring-database-to-server-net-core-should-not-be-using-a-file-backed

Answer (score 1):

It's similiar to the Brando's answer but this one uses a stable package:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql;
```

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql/)

Using the same variables in the Brando's answer, the code will be like this:

```
var azureSqlServer = "xxxxxxx"+".database.windows.net";
var azureSqlServerName = "xxxxxxx";

        SqlManagementClient managementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));

        var exportParams = new DacExportParameters()
        {
            BlobCredentials = new DacExportParameters.BlobCredentialsParameter()
            {
                StorageAccessKey = storageKey,
                Uri = new Uri(baseStorageUri)
            },
            ConnectionInfo = new DacExportParameters.ConnectionInfoParameter()
            {
                ServerName = azureSqlServer,
                DatabaseName = azureSqlDatabase,
                UserName = adminLogin,
                Password = adminPassword
            }
        };
        var exportResult = managementClient.Dac.Export(azureSqlServerName, exportParams);
```

Comment: yeah but what happens if you try to import a very large db from a local bacpac? It will probably crash since the entire file would be uploaded to the memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` to export your database to a `.bacpac`  file and store it in a blob. To do this, there are few things you need to do.

1. Create an AZAD (Azure Active Directory) application and Service Principal that can access resources. Follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) for a comprehensive guide.
2. From the first step, you are going to need "Application (client) ID", "Client Secret", and "Tenant ID".
3. Install `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` NuGet packages, and import  `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent`, `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent`, and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication` namespaces.
4. Replace the placeholders in the code snippets below with proper values for your usecase.
5. Enjoy!

   ```
       var principalClientID = "<Applicaiton (Client) ID>";
       var principalClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>";
       var principalTenantID = "<TenantID>";


       var sqlServerName = "<SQL Server Name> (without '.database.windows.net'>";
       var sqlServerResourceGroupName = "<SQL Server Resource Group>";


       var databaseName = "<Database Name>";
       var databaseLogin = "<Database Login>";
       var databasePassword = "<Database Password>";


       var storageResourceGroupName = "<Storage Resource Group>";
       var storageName = "<Storage Account>";
       var storageBlobName = "<Storage Blob Name>";


       var bacpacFileName = "myBackup.bacpac";


       var credentials = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(principalClientID, principalClientSecret, principalTenantID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
       var azure = await Azure.Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

       var storageAccount = await azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroupAsync(storageResourceGroupName, storageName);


       var sqlServer = await azure.SqlServers.GetByResourceGroupAsync(sqlServerResourceGroupName, sqlServerName);
       var database = await sqlServer.Databases.GetAsync(databaseName);

       await database.ExportTo(storageAccount, storageBlobName, bacpacFileName)
               .WithSqlAdministratorLoginAndPassword(databaseLogin, databasePassword)
               .ExecuteAsync();
   ```