# Error restoring database to server: .NET Core should not be using a file backed model

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, azure, bacpac

I was always able to restore a bacpac to a SQL Server in Azure using a local file like this:

```
ds = new DacServices(connectionString);         
ds.ImportBacpac(BacPackage.Load(filePath), dbTargetName, 
                new DacImportOptions { 
                    ...
                    }
                });
```

Then I looked for a way to not fully load the bacpac to the memory, so I discovered that `BacPackage.Load` has a 2nd argument that supposed to take care just for that so I used it like this:

```
BacPackage.Load(filePath, DacSchemaModelStorageType.File)
```

When I added that usage of the 2nd parameter, I started getting an exception when trying to restore the bacpac:

> Error restoring data base to server: .NET Core should not be using a file backed model

Why can't I use it like that? I don't want to load the bacpac to the memory, so what can I do?

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/12730

Comment: Is your database mounted on a SQL Server or are you just reading directly from the MDF file.  It looks like you are using Entity and the database is mounted on a Server.  So the only memory you are using is based on the Select statement which loads only the items in the Select into your model.  So adding a Where to the select will limit the amount of the database that gets loaded into your model.  If your data has a DateTime you can limit the amount of data that gets loaded by the Date.

Comment: @MartinCostello this bug there seems like a build error? while mine is a runtime error

Comment: @jdweng we're talking here about restoring a full database from an already made bacpac file. I can't control its creation itself - I get an already made one

Comment: Instead of moving entire database in one chunk (one bacpac) do it in pieces.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/migrating-from-sql-server-to-azure-sql-database-using-bacpac-files

Comment: @jdweng could you please point me to the right place in the link? I can't seem to find somewhere there that describes how can you divide a bacpac into pieces. What i did manage to read is that they are talking about uploading the bacpac to azure as a blob, while I'm importing it locally from my machine

Comment: If yoi uhave multiple tables you can move one table at a time.  Each table you can use a WHERE ot divide into pieces.

Comment: @jdweng i have only a given bacpac file with no information what's in it.

Comment: It is a zip file with an extension bacpak.  You can open with ZIP tool.  You may need to rename file to open.

Comment: @jdweng We are talking about doing it with a C# code, not manually

Comment: You can rename a file in c#.  Also there is unzip libraries in c#,.

Comment: do you have a code example that showing how I can send one table at a time and how then I can make the actual import in Azure with all these tables?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is optional

Just do:

```
BacPackage.Load(filePath)
```

When I added the second parameter, I had the same issue, when removed it worked fine.

Comment: This entire question is about how I know its optional but I do want to use it..